# Firebase systems folder located in users document directory - iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an application using Firestore and I want my application to be able to use the default files app.

However, after I set up the app to use the iOS files app, it shows a `firestore` folder, and within that contains `_FIRAPP_DEFAULT`, then within that additional subfolders etc.

I'd expect this to be located in the `.libraryDirectory` not the `.documentDirectory`

**So now if I support the files app, users will see this folder and contents, which I class as system files that my users should no be seeing.**

Is there a fix for this ? Can I specify where the firebase folder is saved? I looked at `FirebaseOptions` but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue without a known workaround. Follow it at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/843

==================

This issue is now fixed, in Version 6.16 - Jan 28 2020

> Changed the location of Firestore's locally stored data from the
>   Documents folder to Library/Application Support, hiding it from users
>   of apps that share their files with the iOS Files app. Important:
>   After a user's data is migrated, downgrading to an older version of
>   the SDK will cause the user to appear to lose data, since older
>   versions of the SDK can't read data from the new location

===================

Comment: Thanks - look like this isn't going to be resolved anytime soon, since that thread started in Feb 2018.

Comment: There has been a recent increased priority because of some related issues and progress on some of its blockers, so it may not be too long - but no promises ...

Comment: So I contacted support, and got this back - Thanks for waiting. Currently, Cloud Firestore SDK manages the saving of data in your cache, and there's no way to modify this.